# R sf calculate average value of each point

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

I have a forty year monthly timeseries dataset. I would like to create `3` new columns (`AvgTMean`, `AvgTMin`, `AvgTMax`) that would be the `average` of `tmean`, `Tmin` and `TMax` for each point in the data (each point will have its own unique average value) respectively. I will then map these average values from any of the 3 average value columns on an interactive.

The purpose is to create a map that shows the 40 year average temperature values.

How can I calculate the average of each point?

Sample data (`sf`):

```
structure(list(Info = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_), tmean = c(22.2395992279053, 22.7657985687256, 
24.4260005950928, 19.601001739502, 21, 24, 26, 21.45, 27.6), Variable = c("tmean", "tmean", 
    "tmean", "tmean", "tmax", "tmax", "tmax", "tmax", "tmax"), 
     year = c(2021L, 2021L, 1980L, 1980L, 2021L, 2021L, 
    2021L, 2021L, 2021L), month = c(11L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L), TMin = c(15, 15.23, 16.12, 13.45, 16.46, 12.11, 11.55, 9.78, 10.56), TMax = c(0, 
    39.69, 40.001, 43.2, 40.6976985931396, 41.7550983428955, 42.1988983154297, 
    41.6512985229492, 40.2621994018555), geometry = structure(list(
        structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 26.2083333333333), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 26.2083333333333
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 
        26.2083333333333), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 26.2083333333333), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 26.0416666666667
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 
        26.0416666666667), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
        structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 26.0416666666667), class = c("XY", 
        "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 26.0416666666667
        ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-80.2083333327448, 
        26.0416666666667), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -80.2083333327448, 
    ymin = 26.0416666666667, xmax = -80.2083333327448, ymax = 26.2083333333333
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84", 
        wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L, class = c("sfc_POINT", 
    "sfc"))), row.names = c(NA, 9L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(Info = NA_integer_, 
tmean = NA_integer_, CITYNAME = NA_integer_, Model = NA_integer_, 
Variable = NA_integer_, Datatype = NA_integer_, Resolution = NA_integer_, 
year = NA_integer_, month = NA_integer_, TMin = NA_integer_, 
TMax = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

    sf_avg = sf %>% 
           summarise(AvgTMean = mean(tmean),
                     AvgTMin = mean(TMin),
                     AvgTMax = mean(TMax)) # Returns the same average value for both the points

# Test static map

qtm(df_df, fill ="AvgTMean", legend = TRUE) +
   tm_add_legend(labels = dff$AvgTMean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble with your example so I make a small reproducible example. You will probably need to adapt it for your needs.

```
# loading lib
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
# data is in tidy format so you have a replicate of 3 points 
pnt_attribute <- data.frame(year = rep(seq(from = 2022 - 40, to = 2021, by = 1),3) 
           , temp1 = c(rnorm(40, mean = 20, sd = 5) 
                    , rnorm(40, mean = 20, sd = 10)
                    , rnorm(40, mean = 15, sd = 5))
 )
# this create a table with 3 points replicate 40 times
pnts <- data.frame(
      id = c(rep(1, 40), 
             rep(2, 40), 
             rep(3,40))
      , x = c(rep(5, 40), 
              rep(1, 40), 
              rep(0, 40))
      , y = c(rep(2, 40), 
              rep(3, 40), 
              rep(1, 40)))
# combine the two df then transorm into sf 
rep_example <- st_as_sf(cbind(pnts,  pnt_attribute), coords = c("x", "y"))
```

Then you create your summary:

```
rep_example_agg <- rep_example |> 
                    group_by(id) |>
                    summarize(AvgTMean = mean(temp1, na.rm = TRUE),
                              AvgTMin  = min(temp1, na.rm = TRUE),
                              AvgTMax  = max(temp1, na.rm = TRUE))
# the result 
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 4 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 1 xmax: 5 ymax: 3
# CRS:           NA
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
# id AvgTMean AvgTMin AvgTMax geometry
# <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <POINT>
# 1     1     19.4    5.92    29.2    (5 2)
# 2     2     20.0   -1.34    40.8    (1 3)
# 3     3     14.6    3.37    26.1    (0 1)
```

I think you either needed the `group_by` of your data are in an other structure.

Good resource:  https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/attr.html#vector-attribute-aggregation